# HTML to JSON conversion in xslt

Tags: html, json, xslt

I want to convert HTML to JSON.. and this the coneversion automation using xslt and my input file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" prefix="dcterms: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ gz: https://www.gazettes.co.uk/metadata">
<head>
<title property="dc:title" about="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/5">Managing the probate process on your own</title>
<meta name="dcterms.format"  content="application/xhtml+xml" />
<meta name="dcterms.subject" xml:lang="en" content="case study" />
<meta name="dcterms.subject" xml:lang="en" content="wills and probate" />
<meta name="dcterms.identifier" content="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/5" />
<meta name="dcterms.relation" content="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/wills-and-probate" />
<meta name="gz.position" content="related pane first" />
<meta name="gz.weight" content="0" />       
</head>
<body>
<article>
<header>
<h1 class="title">User profile: Managing the probate process on your own</h1>
</header>
<dl>                   
<dt>Created date</dt>
<dd about="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/5" property="dcterms:created" content="2013-03-28">28/03/2013</dd>
<dt>Publication date</dt>
<dd about="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/5" property="dcterms:issued"  content="2013-03-28">28/03/2013</dd>                
</dl>
<section class="abstract-short" about="https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/7" property="dcterms:abstract">
<p>Lisa Rutherford is a shop assistant, whose grandmother died last year. As the personal representative …</p>
</section>
<section class="content">                
<p>Lisa Rutherfas keen to keep costs down and if possible not involve any lawyers.</p>
<p>Before dealas infor, she wishes &#x201C;there was more easily accessible information&#x201D; and that &#x201C;the process was simpler and easier to navigate&#x201D;.</p>
<p>Lisa describt orderal is an online checklist that could have guided me step by step through the process.&#x201D;</p>
<p>Inforobate process.</p>
<p>As peopls of probate.</p> 
<em>The above study pr this semi-fictional account is based on extensive research and user profile analysis.</em>
<em><a href="mailto:commissioning@tso.co.uk">commissioning@tso.co.uk</a></em>
</section>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

and my xslt is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:jn="http://www.json.org" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="html">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain" indent="yes"/>

<!-- strip whitespace from whitespace-only nodes -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- handle element nodes -->
<xsl:template match="html:html">
{
"title": "<xsl:value-of select="html:head/html:title"/>",
<xsl:if test="html:head/html:title/@about!=''">
        "identifier": "<xsl:value-of select="html:head/html:title/@about"/>",
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="html:head/html:meta[@content='block' or @content='footer' or @content='page' or @content='news']/@content!=''">
"subject": "<xsl:value-of select="html:head/html:meta[@content='block' or @content='footer' or @content='page' or @content='news']/@content"/>",
</xsl:if>
"relation": ["<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="substring-after(html:head/html:meta[@name='dcterms.relation']/@content,'https://www.gazettes.co.uk/')">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(html:head/html:meta[@name='dcterms.relation']/@content,'https://www.gazettes.co.uk')"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>Global</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>"],
"created": "<xsl:value-of select="
concat(html:body/html:article/html:dl/html:dd[@property='dcterms:created']/@content,'T23:59:00')"/>",
"issued": "<xsl:value-of select="concat(html:body/html:article/html:dl/html:dd[@property='dcterms:issued']/@content,'T23:59:00')"/>",
<xsl:if test="html:head/html:meta[@name='gz.position']">
"position": "<xsl:value-of select="html:head/html:meta[@name='gz.position']/@content"/>",
</xsl:if>
"weight": "<xsl:value-of select="html:head/html:meta[@name='gz.weight']/@content"/>",
"source": {
"uri": "<xsl:value-of select="html:body/html:article/html:dl/html:dd[@property='dc:source']/@content"/>",
"text": "<xsl:value-of select="html:body/html:article/html:dl/html:dd[@property='dc:source']/text()"/>"
        },
"creator": {
"uri": "[creator]",
"text": "[creatorName]"
        },
"rights": "[copyrightattributionURI]",
<xsl:for-each select="html:body/html:article/html:section">
<xsl:if test="./@class!=''">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@class"/><xsl:text>: "</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="./*">

<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:copy-of select="node()"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()!= last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>    
}
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my output is

```js
{
"title": "Managing the probate process on your own",

"identifier": "https://www.gazettes.co.uk/content/5",

"relation": ["/wills-and-probate"],
"created": "2013-03-28T23:59:00",
"issued": "2013-03-28T23:59:00",

"position": "related pane first",

"weight": "0",
"source": {
"uri": "",
"text": ""
},
"creator": {
"uri": "[creator]",
"text": "[creatorName]"
},
"rights": "[copyrightattributionURI]",
"abstract-short: "<p>Lisa Rutherford is a shop assistant, whose grandmother died last year. As the personal representative …</p>, "content: "
<p>Lisa Rutherford is a shop assistant, whose grandmother died last year. As the personal representative of her grandmother’s
   will, Lisa was responsible for dealing with her grandmother’s affairs. At the time, Lisa’s family was on a tight budget and
   she was keen to keep costs down and if possible not involve any lawyers.
</p>
<p>Before dealing with her grandmother’s will, Lisa had only an introductory knowledge of probate and was informed by friends
   and colleagues on what needed to be done. Reflecting on her experience, she wishes “there was more easily accessible information”
   and that “the process was simpler and easier to navigate”.
</p>
<p>Lisa describes how it was difficult for her to understand what forms she needed to sign and in what order she should have
   proceeded with probate. She concludes, “what would have been ideal is an online checklist that could have guided me step by
   step through the process.”
</p>
<p>Informed of what would have made Lisa’s experience easier, The Gazette has included in its new Wills and Probate service an
   online probate checklist that will guide each user step by step through the probate process.
</p>
<p>As people like Lisa increasingly choose to undertake the probate process themselves, there is a growing need for an easily
   accessible and easy to navigate online probate checklist. In order to meet this need, The Gazettes new Wills and Probate service
   includes a comprehensive online checklist that guides each person step by step through the legalities and practicalities of
   probate.
</p><em>The above study profiles personal and professional needs in relation to The Gazettes services. While the identity of the individual
   and the context of his or her circumstance have been altered, this semi-fictional account is based on extensive research and
   user profile analysis.</em><em><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="mailto:commissioning@tso.co.uk">commissioning@tso.co.uk</a></em>    
}
```

here my problem, `<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="mailto:commissioning@tso.co.uk">commissioning@tso.co.uk</a>` is having default namespace that i want to remove. i.e., it should be `<a  href="mailto:commissioning@tso.co.uk">commissioning@tso.co.uk</a>`

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the namespace of your elements (from the XHTML namespace to no namespace), then you can't use xsl:copy-of, which copies them unchanged; you need to use a recursive template that reconstructs each element:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="no-ns">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="no-ns"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you please explain this with some real time example? please.

Comment: If you don't understand it, then you need to do some reading. Get yourself a good XSLT textbook. Or at least, tell us which part of it you don't understand.